# mitmdump replacement pattern construction

Tags: mitmproxy

I'm trying to specify replacements in mitmdump but am having trouble getting the syntax right. What I want to do is replace the entire path in a request with a fixed string.

I've tried -R :~bq:/*:/example.html but that results in "Invalid filter pattern: ~bq"

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `~q` not `~bq` as filter pattern. Because `~bq` needs regex itself like `~bq regex`. The error "Invalid filter pattern" is caused by using ~bq with regex part.

More details https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/pull/2589#issuecomment-340426254

Comment: Thanks. What's the correct syntax to use to match the entire path in the request?
-R :~q:/:/example.html 
inserts example.html rather than replacing the whole of the path in the request. I want to steer all requests to specific page...

Comment: not sure if I understand your question clearly, try this `':~q:/.*$:/example.html'`?

Comment: Cheers Kevin, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: Though the console output looked promising, it turned out that was not quite what I needed; what I should be doing is changing the path portion of the request whilst retaining the other attributes, in particular MIME type (otherwise I get a 406 error). Having tried and failed, if anyone could point me in the right direction for that, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: How would I restrict replacements to only the path portion of a URL? That would be group 3 in the following regex: (http[s]?:\/\/)?([^\/\s]+\/)(.*), i.e. the (.*) portion?

Comment: Perhaps the question should be, how do I restrict the replacements to GETs only? I can't work the ~m operator in to the command, I get Invalid filter specification: ~m GET -R :~q:/.*$:/example.html. 

When I review pcaps on the target server the request has "HTTP/1.1" appended; that does not show on the mitmdump console. Why?

Also, what does "with no response" mean in relation to the ~q filter description?

Is there anywhere that has a decent collection of of real-world examples of mitmdump being used in reverse mode?

Comment: `-R :~q:/.*:/example.html` matches (too many things). The documentation states that "Regexes are Python-style", and `-R :~q:GET /.*:GET /example.html` works fine in a Python regex checker, but fails to trigger replacements. I see the exact same request (GET /test.html) - which worked with the first regex - in the console, but it's not acted on. Is this my mistake, or a bug? @kevin